# Java properties.store() Should only encode the characters that are in the charset

Tags: java, properties

I need to create a properties file with the character set ISO_8859_1. In this file I have to store characters that are not part of this character set. Changing the character set to e.g. UTF-8 is unfortunately not an option. However, those characters are already passed as Unicode escape sequences. The goal is that they are not interpreted when the file is created, but remain as Unicode escape sequences.

How it should be: 
\u00C2 -> Â 
\u2193 -> \u2193

How it currently is: 
\u00C2 -> Â 
\u2193 -> ?

This is what my current store method looks like:

```
properties.store(new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(sourceAndDestinationFile), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)), null);
```

Is there any way to tell the store method to only encode what the charset allows?

Answer (score 0):

To **exactly** fulfill your requirements, you have to write specific code.

The best option out of the box is to use the `store​(OutputStream, String)` version. The `store​(Writer, String)` method does not support `\uxxxx` unicode escaping (it assumes that you use a Writer capable of representing all relevant characters).

The `store​(OutputStream, String)` version explicitly supports ISO-8859-1, using `\uxxxx` unicode escaping. The only difference is that it uses this escaping too often, for everything that isn't ASCII printable, so `Â` will get written as `\u00c2`.

The rationale is that the resulting files are effectively ASCII encoded, and thus compatible with a broad range of readers (using ASCII, many ISO-8859 versions and derivatives, UTF-8, ...).

Comment: thank you, I had already suspected that..

Is there any chance that you can give me a short example of what this particular code might look like? Unfortunately I don't know anything about encoding yet

Comment: I've never done it. I'd look into the `Properties.store​(OutputStream, String)` implementation to get inspired.